# What's the meaning of the preposition "by" in 'a party by counsel'?

Tags: meaning-in-context, difference, legalese

[Source:](http://www.law.cornell.edu/supremecourt/text/287/45) *Powell v Alabama* (1932)

> ...He requires the
>   guiding hand of counsel at every step in the proceedings
>   against him. Without it, though he be not guilty, he faces the
>   danger of conviction because he does not know how to
>   establish his innocence. If that be true of men of intelligence,
>   how much more true is it of the ignorant and illiterate, or those
>   of feeble intellect. If in any case, civil or criminal, a state or
>   federal court were arbitrarily to refuse to hear **a party by
>   counsel**, employed by and appearing for him, it reasonably
>   may not be doubted that such a refusal would be a denial of a
>   hearing, and, therefore, of due process in the constitutional
>   sense.
>
> [2.1.](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/party#party-2) A group of people taking part in a particular activity or trip:

Am I right that the following definition applies? If so, should this be written as **party OF counsel**?

Comment: No. Party is a side in a trial. Listen to a party by counsel means that I listen to a party, as represented by counsel. So instead of listening to you, I listen to your lawyer. In legal texts, _party_ almost _exclusively_ means _side in a dispute or contract_ (as in _third party_!). The fact that _party_ is later referred to as _him_ should have been a hint that _party_ is one person ;)

Comment: read it as refuse to hear 'a representative of the defendant' 'defendant, by his representative'

Comment: @Tetsujin: with the small detail that _party_ can also be the plaintiff :)

Comment: http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=mbNl_T-bFzcC&pg=PA51&lpg=PA51&dq=%22party+by+counsel%22&source=bl&ots=zMy8920SuZ&sig=Aaii-9iEp5-XI9G30Q2psX3HBlc&hl=en&sa=X&ei=FOB-VJmZJYKv7AbdnIHgBA&ved=0CDMQ6AEwAw#v=onepage&q=%22party%20by%20counsel%22&f=false makes it clearer, using that precise example

Comment: @oerkelens for sure, I was just going by context & that I've read more extracts from law books since I started answering Law Area's posts than I ever previously thought healthy :P

Comment: I have edited the question's title to clarify it.

Comment: When you have to ask what "party" means in a legal context, it is high time to get a decent dictionary of legal terminology (e.g. Black's).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In legal contexts, a party can represent himself or be represented by counsel|solicitor|lawyer. In the phrases "to hear a party *by counsel*" or "to hear a party *by himself*" the preposition "by" means "as represented by".  It is a legal usage.

![The statutes of practical utility [1235-1895]: arranged in alphabetical and chronological order : with notes and indexes, Volume 10. Joseph Chitty, Great Britain, John Mounteney Lely
Sweet and Maxwell, limited, 1895.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TAlj9.png)

*The statutes of practical utility [1235-1895]*: arranged in alphabetical and chronological order : with notes and indexes, Volume 10. Joseph Chitty, Great Britain, John Mounteney Lely.